# How to read any format of file to string for further compression with Huffman algorithm

Tags: c++, compression, readfile

How to read any format of file(doc, pdf, jpeg)? My version works only with txt so i am not able to properly decompress file.

My function for read from input file:

```
    std::string getDataFromFileToString(std::string &fName)
    {
    std::string s;
    std::ifstream fr(fName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!fr.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "File \"" << fName << "\" does not exist\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        char c;
        while(fr.get(c))
            s.push_back(c);
    fr.close();
    return s;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it only handles text files correctly, you probably need to open the files in binary mode:

change

`std::ifstream fr(fName, std::ios_base::in);`

to

`std::ifstream fr(fName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary);`

and make similar changes to your output file.

Comment: It helped me. Also I changed string to vector<int>